# How can this if block evaluate false?

Tags: java, spring, conditional-statements

```
    @GetMapping("/menu/sort")
    public String returnMenuSorted(
            @RequestParam(value = "sortField", required = false) String sortField,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortDir", required = false) String sortDir,
            @RequestParam(value = "category", required = false) String category,
            Model model) {
            System.out.println(category);
            System.out.println(category == null);

        return "menu";
}
```

Here is what i see in console. Category is null, but category == null - false.

[image]

Comment: That means that the variable category points to the string "null" (4 characters long)

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt, you are right! I didn't even think RequestParam would give me null as a String.

Comment: @Mark_Daniels If your query string is `?category=null` then yes, it will